# expected: START_TAG SOAP error

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, android-asynctask

Inside my app I've build a reporting system that uploads errors users might have encountered to my server. I am receiving this error from several users. I haven't been able to reproduce it or to figure out what is causing it.

My app calls a SOAP server several times causing the error below:

OS: Android 4.4.2

> Exception = expected: START_TAG
>   {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG
>   @2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4340df58)
>
> StackTrace = [org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2056),
>   org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127),
>   org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100),
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195),
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95),
>   com.xxxx.engine.ws.xxxMobileService$ServiceCallTask.doInBackground(xxxtMobileService.java:227),
>   com.xxxx.engine.ws.xxxtMobileService$ServiceCallTask.doInBackground(xxxMobileService.java:192),
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288),
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237),
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112),
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587),
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)]

Does anyone have any ideas to what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that connectivity issues are the cause. The XMLParser expects a START_TAG. If the parser doesnt even get this far, then its fair to assume it recieved no data. Assuming the soap server isnt overloaded and causing time outs i would expect a loss of connectivity on the side of the android devices.